# Server Error in '/' Application. Resource Cannot Be Found. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 C Sharp and I have this error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /ClerkBooking/ConfirmBooking/22

In my controller I have:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Booking Clerk")]
    public ActionResult ConfirmBooking(int id = 0)
    {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
            //Find the booking
            Booking booking = db.Bookings.Find(id);

            //Get RoomID of Preferred Room.
            int roomId = Convert.ToInt32(db.Rooms.Find(booking.PreferredRoom));

            //Set RoomID of Booking.
            booking.RoomId = roomId;

            //Save Changes.
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

So im not sure why its not finding the method even though its in the correct place. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: And my link to it is: <td>@Html.ActionLink("Confirm Booking", "ConfirmBooking", new {id = booking.BookingId})</td>

Comment: Most importantly: Does your ConfirmBooking controller have an Index view?

Comment: something is not right there in your ActionLink. I don't believe your controller name or method name is Confirm Booking. 2 separate words there

Comment: replace int id = 0 with int id

Answer (score 2):

Your action link `@Html.ActionLink("Confirm Booking", "ConfirmBooking", new {id = booking.BookingId})` is going to make a `GET` request, but you put an `[HttpPost]` attribute on the action.

You'll probably want to make the link a button inside of a form post instead of an action link.

Here's an example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmBooking", "ClerkBooking", new { id = booking.BookingId }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Booking" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are adding your AntiForgeryToken to your html file?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Account")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

If not then probably asp.net mvc is blocking to reach your controller.

Also do not forget to check your Global.asax with the parameters:

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "ClerkBooking", action = "ConfirmBooking", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Otherwise you have to declare your id object from outside.

```
 $.ajax("/ClerkBooking/ConfirmBooking/?id=22", {
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {

               //Do Something

                }
            }
        }).fail(function () {
                         //Do Something
        });
```

Comment: AntiForgeryToken confirmation happens later on in the request, it wouldn't cause a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your controller is called "ClerkBooking" and remove the `[HttpPost]` decoration from the method.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. `HttpPost` should be used for actions that modify data.